# meaning of "to be" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/LxWeWbrzqA8). It is right at the beginning. Here it goes:

> [Speaker 1] Mr. and Mrs. Mountbatten-Windsor, correct?
>
> [Speaker 2] Well, to be.

Does speaker 2 mean *yes we are*?

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bride-husband-parent-etc-to-be

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Speaker (2) means "we will be" in the future. They are not yet 'Mr. and Mrs. Mountbatten-Windsor' because they are not yet married. The phrase 'to be' can mean 'in the near future'. A bride to be is a woman who will soon be married. A mother to be is a woman pregnant for the first time. These phrases can be hyphenated e.g. bride-to-be. The introductory 'well' is a polite way of introducing a correction.

Answer (score 15):

"*husband and wife to be*" is an idiom that refers to a couple that are currently **engaged** to be married, but are **not actually married yet**.

When the first speaker says "*Mr. and Mrs. Mountbatten-Windsor, correct?*", this implies that they are *already* married. (In English, a married, mixed-gender couple who share a last name are sometimes referred to as "*Mr. and Mrs. ____* ".)

So the response "*Well, to be.*" could be re-written as "*Well, we're not married yet, but we will be.*"